# Menu key remaps itself in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xmodmap

I've gotten some good advice from other answers to the question about how to remap my menu key. The solution I settled on has me setting the following in  `.bashrc`

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = Hyper_R'
```

This works well for a little while. However, sometime later, the menu key reverts to popping up menus. I have not been able to tie this occurrence to a specific system event, though I do find that it happens sometimes after my screen (not computer) sleeps. Any advice on how to figure out what's reverting my remapping and prevent that?

EDIT: I figured out the cause of the remap-- a poorly-powered USB hub intermittently cut power to my keyboard, which caused the key remapping to reset. That begs the question, how do enforce key remaps on unplugging and plugging back in my keyboard?

Comment: The man page of xmodmap recommand to put it in ~/.xmodmaprc